# Rails4: How to ignore the same value in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to do is to display the same value for only first time in the each loop.

For example, "Day 1" is displayed in the first loop even if there are a lot of `a.day = 1`.

I tried some codes, but I couldn't. Please advise me on how to display the value.

View code;

```
  <% @article.each do |a| %>
    <h3>Day<%= a.day %></h3>
    <strong><%= a.title %></strong><br>
  <% end %>
```

Schema;

```
  create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "day"
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for help with. For example, you mention the first loop, there is only 1 loop in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you're trying to group titles with the same day under a single heading. You can achieve this using `group_by` as follows:

```
# `group_by` returns a hash with days as keys and arrays of matching articles as values
<% @article.order(:day).group_by(&:day).each do |day, articles| %>
  <h3>Day <%= day %></h3>

  # we then iterate over the articles matching this day
  <% articles.each do |article| %>
    <strong><%= article.title %></strong><br/>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can read more about `group_by` in the [Enumerable docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

Comment: Wouldn't this be better achieved by defining a scope in the model and calling that scope from the controller.

Comment: You could refactor in a variety of ways; the solution above leaves some things to be desired architecturally, but it illustrates the answer in the context that the question was posed.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is get the unique value directly on ActiveRecord's model.

However, you could use `uniq` method:

```
<% @articles.each.uniq { |article| article.day } do |a| %>
  <h3>Day<%= a.day %></h3>
  <strong><%= a.title %></strong><br>
<% end %>
```

Hope this help :)